# Change runtimepath of Gvim on Windows 10

Tags: vimrc, gvim, microsoft-windows

This's kind of odd question but I can't change the runtimepath of gvim to comply the same manner like under linux (plugins put under .vim)

I tried to append .vim at the begin of runtimepath like: `set runtimepath^=~/.vim/,$VIMRUNTIME`, it doesn't work.

The workaround solution is use mklink command of windows to make .vim as a softlink of vimfiles folder `mklink /D .vim vimfiles`, but really don't expect this.

So is there a way to make vim to look into .vim folder instead of vimfiles on windows 10?

P/S: I'm trying to use packages to manage plugins.

Comment: why do you need this?

Comment: Why don't I need it?

Comment: because there must be a reason, why you want to change your vimruntime setting? Seriously, Vim works without changing your runtimepath, so what is the reason you want to change it?

Comment: Change runtimepath is nothing special and is an option to users. That's open-source way imo. Windows support . files so there's no reason why it doesn't work.

Comment: If youre just trying to manage plugins try [vim-plug](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug). Really great and easy to use and it manages all your plugings amazingly

Comment: What plugin manager are you using at the moment?

Comment: @liden: at start of this question I use Vundle but now I use native plugin manager of vim8.

Comment: of course it should work and it works for me. So I am wondering what the reason is that you need to change your runtime path.

Comment: I'd like to have same view on multiple platforms. Too lazy to remember the name folder itself, vimfiles? :). Note that if you tested with gvim8 on  windows 10 and set runtimepath worked for you. Should you mind to share the answer?

Comment: This works for me: `set rtp^=~/.vim` I have that in my `$MYVIMRC` file and use it under windows 10, even though I do not use `~/.vim` folder anymore.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt: Doesn't work for me, same set as my code, I tried both _vimrc and .vimrc.

Comment: did you check with `gvim --clean`? See also the [faq](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-2.5) for debugging

Comment: gvim --clean and reload .vimrc doesn't work. I'll live with this, don't have time to work on it anymore. Thanks all.